# Get column names and frequency from a table that looks like a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, summary

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
'Part Number' 'Person Working'
'A'           'James'
'B'           'Brian'
'A'           'Andrea'
'C'           'Tiffany'
```

and so on for thousands of rows. The same part can have multiple people assigned to it. I'm pretty bad at summarizing data in **R**, but I'm able to produce (in the console) a table that looks like a frequency matrix by typing:

```
table(df$partnumber, df$personworking)
```

and it spits out unique items as rows, and every person working's name as a column. The values are a 0 or a 1 depending on if they are working that part.

What I'm looking for is a way to summarize this information in a digestible format that says, per item:

```
Part Number   NumWorkers    Names
A             3             "James, Andrea"
B             1             "Brian"
C             1             "Tiffany"
```

I'm also struggling with getting my table into a data frame. I've tried:

```
thedataframe <- data.frame(thetable[,])
```

but I'm not getting very far. I want to sum the amount of people working each unique part, and concat and print each column name that has a one as a value for a given part.

What is the best way to summarize this data in Base **R**?

Comment: What is wrong with my methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method you could use in base R with `aggregate`:

```
dfAgg <- do.call(data.frame,
           aggregate(df$Person, list(df$Parts),
                     FUN=function(x) c(length(x), paste(x, collapse=", "))))
# add nicer names
names(dfAgg) <- c("Parts", "Count", "Person")
```

Aggregate allows you to run a function over groups. In this instance, we are running a function that returns both the count of individuals (via `length`) and their names (via `paste`).

Here is the sample data I used to test this.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame("Parts"=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace=T),
                  "Person"=sample(c("James", "Brian", "Sam", "Tiff", "Sandy"), 
                                  10, replace=T), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'partnumber', get the number of rows (`.N`) and `paste` the 'personworking' in each 'partnumber'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(NumWorkers = .N, Names = toString(personworking)) , by = partnumber]
```

---

or we could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(partnumber) %>%
   summarise(NumWorkers = n(), Names = toString(personworking))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$partnumber, FUN = function(x) 
   data.frame(NumWorkers = length(x$personworking), Names = toString(x$personworking))))
```